# Visual Studio 2017 Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So, I feel like I don't have all of the Visual Studio components that I need on my personal computer. For example, when I create a new ASP.NET application on the school computer, it generates files with it (program.cs, startup.cs, and appsettings.json), but those don't exist when I try to create a project on my laptop.

I just had a huge issue trying to get Scaffold-DbContext to work (and after about an hour of digging, finally found the commands to run in Package Manager Console that would allow that much to work). I'm sure there are other things I'm completely missing and don't realize it yet.

What do I need to do to get these files to be generated when I create a new project? Are there other things that I haven't installed for Visual Studio yet that I probably should? I'm really at a complete loss here.

Comment: What do you need to install depends on what you need. I personally can not make a ASP.NET application, because I never installed the components. I do not make these type of application, nor at work, nor at home. _(I have/use only basic C# (GUI+console), C++ and nothing more)_ Therefore there is no real answer for you. You should figure your self what components and packages do you need for your project.

Comment: I think this comes down to not reading the manual or following the syllabus your teacher has put together. You should follow an offical guide on ASP.Net and EntityFramework to the letter. Here is a perfect one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views

Answer (score 1):

Bring up Visual Studio. Click on `Tools`. Click `Get Tools and Features...`
Compare whats installed with what you have at school.

These three will do most of what your looking for:

```
.Net desktop development
ASP.NET and web development
Data storage and processing
```

Also look at the versions `Help` `About Microsoft Visual Studio`